# How do I support passing a unique job name via environment variable to a Spring Batch Job?

Tags: spring-batch, aws-batch

I'm just getting started with using Spring Batch.  I'm working on a command line launcher using AWS Batch with a Docker image.  Trying to just sort the job instance naming.

Would it be acceptable to use a @Value for the below literal string in the jobBuilder?   Essentially I'm passing in S3 File keys which will be unique values already as I have a task that's grabbing the file before my FlatFileReader runs. The goal being to facilitate retries against the job when required due to a failure.

```
  @Bean
    public Job jobParametersJob() {

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("PassedInValue")
                .start(step1())
                .next(step2())
                .next(step3())
                .build();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving by using a job incrementer that implements JobParametersIncrementer.  Note in my case, I'm not currently passing in any job parameters so this is setting them here as my parameters are currently just passed in via environment variables to the docker container.

```
public class JobIncrementer implements JobParametersIncrementer {

@Value("${s3filekey}")
String s3filekey;

@Override
public JobParameters getNext(JobParameters jobParameters) {
    return new JobParametersBuilder().addString("s3filekey",s3filekey).toJobParameters();

}...//then in job configuration...

    @Bean
    public Job jobParametersJob() {

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("jobParametersJob")
                .incrementer(jobIncrementer)
                .start(step1())
                .next(step2())
                .next(step3())
                .build();

    }
```

Comment: You said `I'm not currently passing in any job parameters` but I think it is a better approach than using a `JobParametersIncrementer`. In your case, you are not "incrementing" any parameter (and this is reflected by your implementation which adds the `s3filekey` as a job parameter without using the `jobParameters` parameter). Since S3 file keys are unique, using the key as a job parameter is a good option IMO, something like `java -jar myjob.jar s3filekey= s3filevalue` and then you can pass the value as an env variable to the entry point of your docker image.